# Sending files over Twitter

Tags: twitter

I want to be able to send a file to my followers. How do I do this?

Comment: 140 bytes per tweet

Comment: @akira Technically Twitter messages should be encoded as UTF-8 so in principle could be more than 140 bytes. :D

Comment: ha :), i knew that tihs was coming. really.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do it directly in Twitter. You need to use a third-party app, such as [TweetCube](http://www.tweetcube.com/).

Comment: I am getting an "Account Suspended" message for this site?

Comment: Beats me. Looks to me like they didn't pay their hosting bill.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload the file anywhere that has public HTTP access, and then use a URL shortener like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) to create a nice tweetable link to that file location.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to host the file in a URL and then tweet the URL to your followers

Comment: by ensuring the url is below 140 bytes; if not, use an url-shortening service :)